# Drawing a simple bar graph in ios, without using Coreplot

Tags: ios, plot, bar-chart

I have two sets of array containing 7 objects, with values in one and dates on another.

I would like to generate a simple bar graph with date on x axis and values on y axis.

I searched google and ofcourse stackoverflow, but I didn't find a satisfactory answer.

In every answer, it's all about Coreplot, which I don't want to use because of it's complexity(Me being a begineer in ios development).

Is there any other way except, CorePlot to achieve such graph? Or Can someone provide me an example to plot using inbuilt apple API'S

Awaiting an answer, Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This could probably be done with dynamically creating views, setting their background colors and then setting their positions/heights according to the values you need. It will be some work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using coreplot, but it is a giant framework which is too good and toodifficult for a begineer like me to consume. So I came across [OVGraph](https://github.com/owenv/OVGraphView), which is a basic framework that does all I want, And it is easy to use as well,

something like this :

```
OVGraphView *graphview=[[OVGraphView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 300) ContentSize:CGSizeMake(960, 300)];

 //customizations go here

[self.view addSubview:graphview];

[graphview setPoints:@[[[OVGraphViewPoint alloc]initWithXLabel:@"today" YValue:@3.2 ],[[OVGraphViewPoint alloc]initWithXLabel:@"yesterday" YValue:@4 ],[[OVGraphViewPoint alloc]initWithXLabel:@"3" YValue:@6 ]]];
```

generates beautiful graphs.

Comment: But isn't this a line graph library? You were looking for a bar graph in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this inside a custom UIView.

In the drawRect method you can calculate the extent of the x-axis and the y-axis. You then need to draw the axes onto the actual screen with the numbers showing the values.

Then you need to work out how thick each bar should be and how tall they need to be.

Then draw them into their relevant spaces along the x-axis.

Before any of this though you need to give is a background colour. Maybe some guide lines so the user can easily read the values...

Or you can use http://www.cocoapods.org to install CorePlot and it will do it all for you.

It is MUCH MUCH MUCH MUCH more difficult to draw the graph yourself than it is sto spend a while learning how to use coreplot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, during my intense test I came across this particular framework [link](https://github.com/owenv/OVGraphView) And it is easy to use and it is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Another option can be [EChart](https://github.com/zhuhuihuihui/EChart) which has `EColumnChart`

[image]

Comment: Thank's it's the easiest chart library :D

Answer (score 0):

This third party project worked nice for me and I found the design much better than most other projects. Unfortunately is paid, but it's always an option :)

http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-bar-chart-view/1836